# How to create an email with send-at datetime (send later / scheduled )

Tags: gmail-api, google-api-java-client

So i am using the gmail java api,

it offers to add custom headers or add an `Date` header with `setSentDate`.

Sadly every header (that i tried) gets ignored and the email is sent immediately.

The method mentioned looks like this

```
    /**
     * Set the RFC 822 "Date" header field. This is the date on which the
     * creator of the message indicates that the message is complete
     * and ready for delivery. If the date parameter is 
     * <code>null</code>, the existing "Date" field is removed.
     *
     * @exception   IllegalWriteException if the underlying
     *          implementation does not support modification
     * @exception   IllegalStateException if this message is
     *          obtained from a READ_ONLY folder.
     * @exception   MessagingException for other failures
     */
    public void setSentDate(Date d) throws MessagingException {
```

So it should work with that function ^ but does not.

How can i force gmail to send the message at a specified date ?

Or is it perhaps a bug that the `Date` header is ignored?

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/19716-schedule-gmail-emails), it offers a Google Apps Script solution for what you want, is this an acceptable workaround?

Comment: @AMolina hi and thx, but no i need the email to live within gmail from start so if someone creates an scheduled email on my side he should find it immediately in gmail in Scheduled folder.

Do you think i should create an issue for this ?